# Ruby - bad output from arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, each

I have a form with a lots of these text inputs:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name[seq]['+dat.id.to_s+']', dat.seq%>
```

After send this form I want to save them to database, I try to get the values from inputs in each loop:

```
unless params[:name].nil?
  params[:name][:seq].each_with_index do |sq, i|
    puts sq
  end
end
```

But the output in terminal is wrong, for example if I have an input with the values

> <%= text_field_tag 'name[seq][25]', 3%>

So I am going to expect the output is **3**, but I will get to terminal this:

```
25
3
```

Is here something important, what I don't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something. Within your `each_with_index` block, `sq` will be an array and that's why you get that output.

So, what's going on here? Well, your `params` will contain this:

```
"name" => { "seq" => { "25" => "3" } }
```

And that means that `params[:name][:seq]` is this:

```
{ "25" => "3" }
```

Then you apply `each_with_index` to that to iterate through the Hash. If you do it like this:

```
params[:name][:seq].each_with_index do |(k,v), i|
  puts "-#{k}-#{v}-"
end
```

you'll see what's going on.

If you just want the `3` then you can iterate over `params[:name][:seq]` as above and just look at `v` inside the block or, if you know what the `'25'` is some other way, you could just go straight there:

```
three = params[:name][:seq]['25']
```

Comment: Thanks, so that mean... the index **i** is here totally useless, right?

Comment: @user984621: Pretty much useless, just an `each` would probably do you just as well.